# how to make looping circular progress with progress indeterminate task?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I have a program that retrieves data, where each retrieval can not be determined its completion time. My idea would be to make a progress that keeps repeating and flagging if the capture is complete.

my current source code, method from main class:

```
public JComponent makeUI(boolean  displayProgressBar) {

if(displayProgressBar){
        jpbCircularProg.setUI(new principal.ProgressCircleUI());
        jpbCircularProg.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(8, 8, 8, 8));
        //Border emptyBorder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder();
        //jpbCircularProg.setBorder(emptyBorder);
        jpbCircularProg.setStringPainted(true);
        jpbCircularProg.setFont(jpbCircularProg.getFont().deriveFont(24f));
        jpbCircularProg.setForeground(Color.ORANGE);
        if(jpbCircularProg.isVisible()==false){
            jpbCircularProg.setVisible(true);
        }
        (new Timer(10, e -> {// percepat
            System.out.println("progressbar on :");
            int iv = Math.min(100, jpbCircularProg.getValue() + 1);
            jpbCircularProg.setValue(iv);
            if(jpbCircularProg.getValue()==100){
                jpbCircularProg.setValue(1);
            }
        })).start();
    }else{
        if(jpbCircularProg.isVisible()==true){
            jpbCircularProg.setVisible(false);
        }
        (new Timer(10, e -> {// percepat
            System.out.println("progressbar on :");
            int iv = Math.min(100, jpbCircularProg.getValue() + 1);
            jpbCircularProg.setValue(iv);
            if(jpbCircularProg.getValue()==100){
                jpbCircularProg.setValue(0);
                jpbCircularProg.setStringPainted(true);
                jpbCircularProg.setVisible(false);
            }
        })).start();
     }

    jPanel2.setOpaque(false);
    jPanel2.add(jpbCircularProg);
    return jPanel2;
}
```

**ProgressCircleUI.java:**

```
public class ProgressCircleUI extends BasicProgressBarUI {
  @Override 
  public Dimension getPreferredSize(JComponent c) {
    Dimension d = super.getPreferredSize(c);
    int v = Math.max(d.width, d.height);
    d.setSize(v, v);
    return d;
  }
  @Override public void paint(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
    Insets b = progressBar.getInsets(); // area for border
    int barRectWidth  = progressBar.getWidth()  - b.right - b.left;
    int barRectHeight = progressBar.getHeight() - b.top - b.bottom;
    if (barRectWidth <= 0 || barRectHeight <= 0) {
      return;
    }

    // draw the cells
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                        RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2.setPaint(progressBar.getForeground());
    double degree = 360 * progressBar.getPercentComplete();
    double sz = Math.min(barRectWidth, barRectHeight);
    double cx = b.left + barRectWidth  * .5;
    double cy = b.top  + barRectHeight * .5;
    double or = sz * .5;
    double ir = or * .5; //or - 20;
    Shape inner = new Ellipse2D.Double(cx - ir, cy - ir, ir * 2, ir * 2);
    Shape outer = new Arc2D.Double(
        cx - or, cy - or, sz, sz, 90 - degree, degree, Arc2D.PIE);
    Area area = new Area(outer);
    area.subtract(new Area(inner));
    g2.fill(area);
    g2.dispose();

    // Deal with possible text painting
    if (progressBar.isStringPainted()) {
      paintString(g, b.left, b.top, barRectWidth, barRectHeight, 0, b);
    }
  }
}
```

Source code diatassaya get from a website then i modified a bit. I give the loop and the result is successful, but when the data retrieval more than once circular progress cycle becomes very fast and always increase faster for next data retrieval. I tried by using `setIntermedinate (true)` but it seems to ProgressBar not a Circular. Please help.

Comment: *"but when the data retrieval more than once circular progress cycle becomes very fast and always increase faster for next data retrieval"* - Make sure you're stopping the `Timer` when you're done, otherwise you're create a new `Timer` each time your start again, which means you would have n+1 `Timer`s running, all updating

Answer (score 1):

> but when the data retrieval more than once circular progress cycle becomes very fast and always increase faster for next data retrieval

You're not stopping the timer, in fact, you seem to be using a second `Timer` to hide the progress bar ... for some reason.

This means, each time you want to use the progress indicator, you create ANOTHER `Timer`, which creates a bunch of competing `Timer`s all changing the state and interfering with each other.

A better and simpler solution would be to create a single `Timer` and simply stop/start it as need, for example

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Arc2D;
import java.awt.geom.Area;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicProgressBarUI;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JProgressBar jpbCircularProg;
        private Timer timer;

        public TestPane() {
            timer = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    int iv = Math.min(100, jpbCircularProg.getValue() + 1);
                    jpbCircularProg.setValue(iv);
                    if (jpbCircularProg.getValue() == 100) {
                        jpbCircularProg.setValue(1);
                    }
                }
            });
            jpbCircularProg = new JProgressBar();
            jpbCircularProg.setUI(new ProgressCircleUI());
            jpbCircularProg.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(8, 8, 8, 8));
            //Border emptyBorder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder();
            //jpbCircularProg.setBorder(emptyBorder);
            jpbCircularProg.setStringPainted(true);
            jpbCircularProg.setFont(jpbCircularProg.getFont().deriveFont(24f));
            jpbCircularProg.setForeground(Color.ORANGE);
            if (jpbCircularProg.isVisible() == false) {
                jpbCircularProg.setVisible(true);
            }

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            add(jpbCircularProg, gbc);

            JButton toggle = new JButton("Toggle");
            toggle.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (timer.isRunning()) {
                        timer.stop();
                    } else {
                        timer.restart();
                    }
                }
            });

            add(toggle, gbc);
        }

    }

    public class ProgressCircleUI extends BasicProgressBarUI {

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize(JComponent c) {
            Dimension d = super.getPreferredSize(c);
            int v = Math.max(d.width, d.height);
            d.setSize(v, v);
            return d;
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
            Insets b = progressBar.getInsets(); // area for border
            int barRectWidth = progressBar.getWidth() - b.right - b.left;
            int barRectHeight = progressBar.getHeight() - b.top - b.bottom;
            if (barRectWidth <= 0 || barRectHeight <= 0) {
                return;
            }

            // draw the cells
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2.setPaint(progressBar.getForeground());
            double degree = 360 * progressBar.getPercentComplete();
            double sz = Math.min(barRectWidth, barRectHeight);
            double cx = b.left + barRectWidth * .5;
            double cy = b.top + barRectHeight * .5;
            double or = sz * .5;
            double ir = or * .5; //or - 20;
            Shape inner = new Ellipse2D.Double(cx - ir, cy - ir, ir * 2, ir * 2);
            Shape outer = new Arc2D.Double(
                    cx - or, cy - or, sz, sz, 90 - degree, degree, Arc2D.PIE);
            Area area = new Area(outer);
            area.subtract(new Area(inner));
            g2.fill(area);
            g2.dispose();

            // Deal with possible text painting
            if (progressBar.isStringPainted()) {
                paintString(g, b.left, b.top, barRectWidth, barRectHeight, 0, b);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Since you're trying to display this as a "intermediate" progress bar, it would be better to wrap up the animation functionality into the UI delegate itself.

The following example makes use of the "intermediate" state of the `JProgressBar` to self animate the progress, managing the `Timer` state itself

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.HierarchyEvent;
import java.awt.event.HierarchyListener;
import java.awt.geom.Arc2D;
import java.awt.geom.Area;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicProgressBarUI;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JProgressBar jpbCircularProg;

        public TestPane() {
            jpbCircularProg = new JProgressBar();
            jpbCircularProg.setUI(new ProgressCircleUI());
            jpbCircularProg.setIndeterminate(true);
            jpbCircularProg.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(8, 8, 8, 8));
            //Border emptyBorder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder();
            //jpbCircularProg.setBorder(emptyBorder);
            jpbCircularProg.setStringPainted(true);
            jpbCircularProg.setFont(jpbCircularProg.getFont().deriveFont(24f));
            jpbCircularProg.setForeground(Color.ORANGE);
            if (jpbCircularProg.isVisible() == false) {
                jpbCircularProg.setVisible(true);
            }

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            add(jpbCircularProg, gbc);

            JButton toggle = new JButton("Toggle");
            toggle.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    jpbCircularProg.setIndeterminate(!jpbCircularProg.isIndeterminate());
                }
            });

            add(toggle, gbc);
        }

    }

    public class ProgressCircleUI extends BasicProgressBarUI {

        private Timer timer;
        private Handler handler = new Handler();

        @Override
        public void installUI(JComponent c) {
            initTimer();
            super.installUI(c);
        }

        protected void initTimer() {
            if (timer == null) {
                timer = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        int iv = Math.min(100, progressBar.getValue() + 1);
                        progressBar.setValue(iv);
                        if (progressBar.getValue() == 100) {
                            progressBar.setValue(1);
                        }
                        progressBar.repaint();
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void startAnimationTimer() {
            timer.restart();
        }

        @Override
        protected void stopAnimationTimer() {
            timer.stop();
        }

        private void initIndeterminateValues() {
            initTimer();
            // we only bother installing the HierarchyChangeListener if we
            // are indeterminate
            progressBar.addHierarchyListener(handler);

            // start the animation thread if necessary
            if (progressBar.isDisplayable()) {
                startAnimationTimer();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Invoked by PropertyChangeHandler.
         */
        private void cleanUpIndeterminateValues() {
            // stop the animation thread if necessary
            if (progressBar.isDisplayable()) {
                stopAnimationTimer();
            }

            progressBar.setValue(0);

            progressBar.removeHierarchyListener(handler);
        }

        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e) {
            String prop = e.getPropertyName();
            if ("indeterminate" == prop) {
                if (progressBar.isIndeterminate()) {
                    initIndeterminateValues();
                } else {
                    //clean up
                    cleanUpIndeterminateValues();
                }
                progressBar.repaint();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize(JComponent c) {
            Dimension d = super.getPreferredSize(c);
            int v = Math.max(d.width, d.height);
            d.setSize(v, v);
            return d;
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
            Insets b = progressBar.getInsets(); // area for border
            int barRectWidth = progressBar.getWidth() - b.right - b.left;
            int barRectHeight = progressBar.getHeight() - b.top - b.bottom;
            if (barRectWidth <= 0 || barRectHeight <= 0) {
                return;
            }

            // draw the cells
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2.setPaint(progressBar.getForeground());
            double degree = 360 * progressBar.getPercentComplete();
            double sz = Math.min(barRectWidth, barRectHeight);
            double cx = b.left + barRectWidth * .5;
            double cy = b.top + barRectHeight * .5;
            double or = sz * .5;
            double ir = or * .5; //or - 20;
            Shape inner = new Ellipse2D.Double(cx - ir, cy - ir, ir * 2, ir * 2);
            Shape outer = new Arc2D.Double(
                    cx - or, cy - or, sz, sz, 90 - degree, degree, Arc2D.PIE);
            Area area = new Area(outer);
            area.subtract(new Area(inner));
            g2.fill(area);
            g2.dispose();

            // Deal with possible text painting
            if (progressBar.isStringPainted() && !progressBar.isIndeterminate()) {
                paintString(g, b.left, b.top, barRectWidth, barRectHeight, 0, b);
            }
        }

        protected class Handler implements HierarchyListener {

            public void hierarchyChanged(HierarchyEvent he) {
                if ((he.getChangeFlags() & HierarchyEvent.DISPLAYABILITY_CHANGED) != 0) {
                    if (progressBar.isIndeterminate()) {
                        if (progressBar.isDisplayable()) {
                            startAnimationTimer();
                        } else {
                            stopAnimationTimer();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I checked your source code, it worked. when I insert and modify a bit to match my project. The ProgressBar issue does not appear in my jpanel when a button is clicked. It looks like ProgressBar is overwritten or may be off-screen. Because if I look at the output, the process goes but ProgressBar does not show. I changed the class you created for Jpanel with Jpanel that I created earlier using the IDE Tools palette. please help me why it happened because i am still a beginner and thank you for taking your time